# Add element to an array in a dictionary in TCL

Tags: arrays, dictionary, tcl

I'm triny to add an element to an array (list?) in a dictionary and can't wrap my head around the problem.

I'm creating a dict from json object, that looks roughly like this:

```
{"channel1":{"badwords":["test", "demo"]}, "channel2":{"badwords":["remove"]}}
```

This JSON is transformed into a dict, and I can access badwords as

```
[dict get $channels "channel1" "badwords"]
```

I need to update the dict by adding a new value to it, basically make it a:

```
{"channel1":{"badwords":["test", "demo", "new"]}, "channel2":{"badwords":["remove"]}}
```

Comment: The above is not really a Tcl dict, but I guess if you do have one, you could use something like `dict set channels channel1 badwords [list {*}[dict get $channels channel1 badwords] new]`. `dict set` is setting a value to a certain (set of) key. `{*}[dict get $channels channel1 badwords]` gets the current list, and then `[list ... ]` is merging the previous list to the new element of the list, being `new`.

Comment: The "above" is a JSON object from which the dict is created via `set channels [json::json2dict [http::data [set t [http::geturl "$remote"]]]]`. Sadly, after trying `dict set $channels channel1 badwords [list {*}[dict get $channels channel1 badwords] "newvalue1"]` and calling `puts [llength [dict get $channels channel1 badwords]]` before and after the line the count dosen't change, so I dont think it works.

Comment: nevermind, I've made a typo - the command should be: `dict set channels channel1 badwords [list {*}[dict get $channels channel1 badwords] "newvalue1"]` (no $ before channels while setting). Thanks for your help - works like a charm now :)

Comment: Yea, sorry, I would have really expected to see a Tcl dict since it's a question about Tcl dict, instead of a JSON ;) All the same, glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are a bit tricky, I find. Rely on the documentation: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm

```
set json {{"channel1":{"badwords":["test", "demo"]}, "channel2":{"badwords":["remove"]}}}
package require json  # from tcllib

set channels [json::json2dict $json]
# ==> channel1 {badwords {test demo}} channel2 {badwords remove}

dict update channels channel1 subdict1 {dict lappend subdict1 badwords "new"}
# or, "dict with" that sets local variables you can manipulate
dict with channels channel1 {lappend badwords "new"}

set channels
# ==> channel1 {badwords {test demo new}} channel2 {badwords remove}
```